# Android Studio - Receive a massage when any file is downloaded

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

How can I get a notification (or more specifically Intent) from BroadcastReceiver, when a file (any file, with any extension) is downloaded?
I searched the site here, and the site of Android developers, and could not find an answer.
Would appreciate help.

Comment: There is no requirement for an app to disclose to third-party developers when users download files. After all, publishing this information has privacy and security ramifications.

Comment: But after all, every download goes through the operating system (I'm talking about downloads that can be seen as notifications, in the download window, not on internal downloads within apps). Is it impossible to communicate with her, in order to know when a download ends?

Comment: "I'm talking about downloads... in the download window" -- you are referring to downloads requested via `DownloadManager`. I have not attempted to spy on downloads made through `DownloadManager` by other apps to know what may be possible there.

Comment: I got you. Thank you for your helps. I'll have to go somewhere else